# Way to get multiple divs containing text with varying font sizes all align to bottom?

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div style="left: 10px; bottom: 50px; font-size: 100px;" objectid="1" class="textObj" id="textObj-1">
        APPLE
    </div>
    <div style="left: 360px; bottom: 50px; font-size: 25px;" objectid="1" class="textObj" id="textObj-1">
        GRAPE
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    border: 1px solid green;
    top: 0;
    height: 500px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
}
.textObj {
    position:absolute;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    display: block;
}
```

[See JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jmchauv/hLeLc8ng/)

These `.textObj` divs are created by my users and can have varying font sizes. I need the text to align to the very bottom of it's own `.textObj` div. The word APPLE should be touching it's own bottom red border, as should the word GRAPE.

**Here is an example of the real application.**

You can see that all of the `.textObj` divs are positioned on top of an image that has horizontal lines on it. This is what I use for testing. In a perfect world, the actual numbers within the `.textObj` divs would be sitting on the horizontal black line, while the red outline stays exactly where it is.

[image]

**Here is an example of the result I would like.**

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Those labels appear to be aligned to the bottom of their containing div.  Can you please be more specific about what you want the final result to be? Also, please post the minimum necessary code for us to reproduce this, but NOT as a screenshot.

Comment: I have updated the post. Sorry about that.

Comment: thanks for updating, and for providing such a clear example! ... now to figure out how to actually solve this one in a way that isn't totally hacky ...

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the advice. Would you mind up voting my question since it makes sense now? :)

Comment: Shameless promotion!  But it is a good question, and the answer is going to be interesting, so ok :)

Comment: Do you need something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/hLeLc8ng/2/

Comment: The problem is the natural white space associated with the actual text characters.  For example, try setting line-height: 70px for the "Apple" div, and that may be the look you want.  But that is not a solution that will work regardless of text height - it's specialized for each font size.  That sum up the problem appropriately?

Comment: Or something more like this? https://jsfiddle.net/hLeLc8ng/3/

Comment: That sums it up perfectly Andrea. I've added an example of the real application to my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your text to sit its baseline on the bottom of the block, remove a tenth of the font's height from the `.textObj` class. `0.9em` is a measure that would do this based on the `font-size` of the block.

If you want them all to sit on the baseline of the container as well, then change the `bottom` property to `0`.

Here's your fiddle, but showing the changes.

https://jsfiddle.net/hLeLc8ng/4/

And as a snippet

```css
#container {
    border: 1px solid green;
    top: 0;
    height: 500px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
}

.textObj {
    position:absolute;
    outline: 1px solid red;
    display: block;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 0.9em;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div style="left: 10px; font-size: 100px;" objectid="1" class="textObj" id="textObj-1">
        APPLE
    </div>
    <div style="left: 360px; font-size: 25px;" objectid="1" class="textObj" id="textObj-1">
        GRAPE
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That won't work. See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jmchauv/87uwouw6/ . Notice that setting the height to .9em still does not vertically align the actual numbers to the very bottom of their respective divs. Also, if you look closely, you can see that the bottom of the 100 is not at the same location as the bottom of the 200. As text gets bigger, the difference becomes larger.

Comment: The problem is even more apparent if you make the font size of the "100" text to 300. You'll notice the the bottom of "100" is almost above the other text.

Comment: @jmchauv Then what about an approach more like this? https://jsfiddle.net/hLeLc8ng/5/

Comment: the positioning that is on each `.textOb`j is very important. This cannot be changed because it is dynamic. When you look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jmchauv/hLeLc8ng/ forget about moving the divs to the bottom of the overall container. The real problem to solve is keeping the divs where they are, but moving the actual text down to the very bottom of each `.textObj` div. In other words, the bottom of each character should be touching the bottom red outline, while the box `.textObj` div stays exactly where it is.

Comment: @jmchauv Why is it important that the text is at the bottom of its containing div and not just in-line with the other text and the grid image base?

Comment: To give you some background: I work on PDF related software. The feature I'm working on allows the user to add and position text objects on a file, click submit, and we actually create a new PDF with these text objects. If you look within my question I state: "Here is an example of the real application.". A user has positioned their text boxes along a horizontal line in the PDF. The browser automatically calculates a line-height for each of these, depending on font size. This is a problem for me. I need to somehow align the text to the bottom of these `.textObj` divs.

Comment: @jmchauv Without knowing the full constraints of what you're trying to achieve and the interface you're using to do it, it's impossible for us to know what is a good compromise for your application. It may well be that it would be more suitable to change the way the user defines these bounding containers than to change the way text flows in an HTML document. If the bottom of the container is the only thing that is important, then you could experiment with having a constant line height. But if the entire bounding divs size is important then another approach will be needed.